# Getting metadata in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a lot of stored procedures which return table result. I figured out dynamic  management view to get metadata of a returned table.

```
create procedure test
    (@p int)
as
begin
    select 'a' AS Col1, 'b' AS Col2
end
```

So, for this stored procedure, this dmv works just fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('EXEC Test @p = 1', NULL, 0)
```

But if I change stored procedure to this

```
alter procedure test
    (@p int)
as
begin
    if @p = 0
    begin
        select 'a' AS Col1, 'b' AS Col2
    end
    else
    begin
        select 1 AS Col1, 2 AS Col2
    end
end
```

That dmv doesn't work - the metadata could not be determined.

Is there a way to determine metadata of a stored procedure as shown in the second example above? Maybe changes in dmv params, etc?

Comment: There error message says it all.   Not sure I like the polymorphic approach... feels like a slippery slope.    https://dbfiddle.uk/tTFbnoYV

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, thanks, but i see that error, i was wondering whether there is other way to get metadata?

Comment: No, for this system DMV to work the query needs to deterministic and return a consistent resultset